# How do you disable the overflow menu of an NSToolbar?

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I've created an `NSToolbar` that has a few items in Interface Builder (and set their visibility priority). When I resize the window, items are removed according to their priority as expected, however an overflow button appears with an empty menu. How can I stop this from happening?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `NSToolbarItem` has a `menuFormRepresentation` property that can be set to `nil` to stop it from appearing in this menu. So, do this on all the items in the toolbar to stop the button from appearing:

```
toolbar?.items.forEach({ (item) in
    item.menuFormRepresentation = nil
})
```